# gnuplot - plot different blocks with different color

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a data like this in a `file.dat`

```
2 2
5 5
7 3

100 102
130 80
116 134

-40 -100
-50 -60
-61 -58
```

I would want to plot each block in different color,

There is no restriction that a specific color, but just some visually different color.

I tried with `linetype` like this:

```
for [IDX=0:2] 'file.dat' i IDX u 1:2 with linespoints linetype IDX
```

it plots all the blocks with different color and obviously only last one is visible.

So what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the right way, but you must have *two* blank lines in order to access different blocks with `index`.

And, you should start at `linetype 1`, because `linetype 0` is a special linetype for the grid lines:

```
2 2
5 5
7 3


100 102
130 80
116 134


-40 -100
-50 -60
-61 -58
```

And the plot command

```
plot for [IDX=0:2] 'file.dat' index IDX u 1:2 with lp lt IDX+1
```

Comment: Hi, how I have to change the command for plotting all the block if I don't know how many block I have? thanks

Comment: @thewoz Use `stats` to calculate the number of blocks,  I think the result is stored in variable `STATS_blocks`