# plot every subsequence with a different color using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a list of 105 sorted values in ascending order. I divided that list in 5 subsequences as shown in the following table:

```
id  Seq1    Seq2    Seq3    Seq4    Seq5
1   696.99  958.79  989.02  1018.28 1078.3
2   869.21  959.26  989.02  1018.28 1078.3
3   898.73  959.44  989.02  1018.28 1078.55
4   898.73  959.44  989.02  1018.28 1078.55
5   898.73  959.44  989.21  1018.28 1078.55
6   898.73  959.44  989.21  1018.28 1078.55
7   898.73  959.44  989.21  1018.28 1078.55
8   898.79  959.44  989.21  1018.52 1078.69
9   898.79  959.51  989.21  1018.52 1078.69
10  898.79  959.51  989.21  1018.52 1078.69
11  899.27  988.52  989.26  1018.52 1078.69
12  899.27  988.65  989.26  1018.52 1078.69
13  899.27  988.65  989.26  1018.52 1078.69
14  899.44  988.65  989.26  1019.0  1078.73
15  928.65  988.65  989.51  1019.0  1078.73
16  928.73  989.0   989.51  1019.26 1078.73
17  929.26  989.0   989.51  1078.3  1078.73
18  958.73  989.0   989.51  1078.3  1078.73
19  958.79  989.02  989.51  1078.3  1078.73
29  958.79  989.02  1013.0  1078.3  1144.2
21  958.79  989.02  1013.0  1078.3  1144.21
```

> My question is how can I plot all the 5 sub-sequences in a continuous
>   manner and each with different color. I used the following script. But
>   the problem is that it is plotting them separately as shown in the
>   following figure.

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash

#set key outside
unset key

set title "5 sequences des prix triés pour 120 jours avant la date de départ"

set xlabel "séquences"
set ylabel "Prix"


# set xlabel "Jour de recherche avant la date de départ"
# set ylabel "Nombre de dates de baisses pour chaque jour de recherche"

set xtics font ", 11"

set datafile separator ","
# set autoscale
set terminal pngcairo dashed
set output 'sequence.png'
set key autotitle columnhead


plot  "test.csv" every 4 u 2:xticlabels(1) w l lw 2 lc 1 ,\
        "test.csv" every 4 u 3:xticlabels(1) w l lw 2 lc 2 ,\
        "test.csv" every 4 u 4:xticlabels(1) w l lw 2 lc 3,\
        "test.csv" every 4 u 5:xticlabels(1) w l lw 2 lc 4,\
        "test.csv" every 4 u 5:xticlabels(1) w l lw 2 lc 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot for [IDX=0:4] 'prix.txt' u ($1 + IDX*21):(column(IDX+2)) title columnhead(IDX+2) w lp
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34760982/352349) I changed your data to just be two columns:

```
1   696.99
2   869.21
3   898.73
4   898.73
5   898.73
6   898.73
7   898.73
8   898.79
9   898.79
10  898.79
11  899.27
12  899.27
13  899.27
14  899.44
15  928.65
16  928.73
17  929.26
18  958.73
19  958.79
20  958.79
21  958.79


22  958.79
23  959.26
24  959.44
25  959.44
26  959.44
27  959.44
28  959.44
29  959.44
30  959.51
31  959.51
32  988.52
33  988.65
34  988.65
35  988.65
36  988.65
37  989
38  989
39  989
40  989.02
41  989.02
42  989.02


43  989.02
44  989.02
45  989.02
46  989.02
47  989.21
48  989.21
49  989.21
50  989.21
51  989.21
52  989.21
53  989.26
54  989.26
55  989.26
56  989.26
57  989.51
58  989.51
59  989.51
60  989.51
61  989.51
62  1013
63  1013


64  1018.28
65  1018.28
66  1018.28
67  1018.28
68  1018.28
69  1018.28
70  1018.28
71  1018.52
72  1018.52
73  1018.52
74  1018.52
75  1018.52
76  1018.52
77  1019
78  1019
79  1019.26
80  1078.3
81  1078.3
82  1078.3
83  1078.3
84  1078.3


85  1078.3
86  1078.3
87  1078.55
88  1078.55
89  1078.55
90  1078.55
91  1078.55
92  1078.69
93  1078.69
94  1078.69
95  1078.69
96  1078.69
97  1078.69
98  1078.73
99  1078.73
100 1078.73
101 1078.73
102 1078.73
103 1078.73
104 1144.2
105 1144.21
```

separated into the 5 groups (double blank lines between each).

Then this:

```
plot for [IDX=0:4] 'prix.txt' index IDX u 1:2 with lp lt IDX+1
```

produces this:
[image]